# Why won't the while loop continue and stop after a user question?

Tags: python, input, while-loop

```
questionnumber=0
color=("Red")
userask=input("What color of the rainbow am I thinking of? ")
color = userask

if color == "Red":
    print("CORRECT")
else:
    print("INCORRECT")
    questionnumber = questionnumber+1
    #print(questionnumber)

while color != "Red":
    userask=input("What color of the rainbow am I thinking of? ")
    color = userask

    if color == "Red":
        print("CORRECT")
    else:
        print("INCORRECT")
        questionnumber = questionnumber+1
        #print (questionnumber)

    if questionnumber>3:
        quitter=input("Do you want to quit? ")
        if quitter == "yes"or"Yes":
            break
        else:
            continue
```

So the idea is you have to guess the correct color which in this case is red. But after three attempts, the program asks the user if they want to quit; if yes, the while loop stops, and if no, the while loop continues for another three attempts. I can't seem to figure out why the loop ends regardless of the user's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that:

```
if quitter == "yes"or"Yes"
```

is based on a misunderstanding of Python logic statements.

It is not interpreted as `if quitter == ("yes"or"Yes")` as you intended, but it is actually interpreted as:

```
if (quitter == "yes") or ("Yes")
```

Any non-blank string evaluates to True, so the `break` is always executed.

A better way of writing this would be:

```
if quitter.lower() == "yes":
```

This converts the contents of `quitter` to lower case and checks that, so you don't need to check upper and lower case, and other variants like "YES".

Answer (score 0):

Please change this statement to as below :

```
if ((quitter == "yes") or (quitter == "Yes")):
```

Answer (score 0):

After prompting the user if they want to quit, change the if statement to

```
if quitter == "yes" or quitter == "Yes":
            break
        else:
            continue
```

The reason the program exits is because it's evaluating the string `'Yes'` on it's own as True which means the or statement evaluates as `True` and thus `break` is ran. You have to specify quitter both before and after the or statement.

```
truth_val = bool('Yes')
print(truth_val)
>>>True
```